# I got a lot of weird answers for this riddle!

Tags: riddle

I found this riddle on the internet and there were some really weird answers. I wanted to see what you would say.
  I have three brothers. Each brother has three brothers. How many are we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one I know!

> 4 brothers in total, and each one can say he has 3 brothers